# How to transfer data(QR Code) from system to Paytm Dynamic QR device

Tags: c#, usb, paytm

As we know, Paytm has launched a Dynamic QR device to display invoice/bill QR Code image.

I have to integrate this device with a billing system(POS), where I have to send QRCode data to this device.

**I have to integrate it using C#.NET**

Note:-
As per the device guidelines, we can transfer data from system to device using USB Port(the serial port communication)
Reference
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after a discussion with Paytm Development Team. They have shared an SDK along with an API that is used to transfer data from POS(PC) to the Paytm Dynamic QR display device.

This SKD has basically main three methods:

1. Show Home Screen on display
2. Show QRCode on display
3. Show Payment Success message on display

Comment: What is the URL parameter for sending Transaction Text message ?